# Using external web space from domain (DNS)

Tags: dns, provider

I got a client that uses provider A for webhosting purposes with domain A. I registered a second domain B on a different provider B for my client.

How can I link to the web folder on provider A with my domain B? I don't want to use a simple redirect - it should be the same as using the web space with domain A. 
(so the url structure &c. will remain)

Edit: I already got the nameservers from provider A, but I don't know how to set and use them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

*Ideally* the best way would be to use whatever control panel provider A has for setting up the domain to work with its hosting. If however it will only allow domain A to be hosted there (which is what I think you mean), then you could use URL masking instead.

This link explains URL masking in detail along with examples:
http://www.willmaster.com/library/web-development/URL-masking.php

Comment: Yes, the problem is that domain B has been purchased on provider B. Provider A has installed the cpanel and domain B is listed there as a parked domain. Don't know whether this is useful or not.